# ¿Cómo agregar un campo al Request?

Tags: laravel

Tengo el siguiente request, y necesito agregar un campo que no envía el formulario,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    Visit::create($request->all());

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully created user!'
    ], 201);
}
```

Agregar aquí `Visit::create($request->all());` el campo `user_id` con el valor `$id = auth()->id();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente puedes agregarlo haciendo esto:

```
Visit::create($request->all() + ['user_id' => auth()->id()]);
```